# Open source replacement for Paint 3D

Tags: windows, open-source, png, jpg

I'm using Paint 3D on Windows when I need to work with images. My particular use case involves using the same image repeatedly with different text.

In paint, once the textbox is closed, your changes are final. I'd like to find a free desktop program (Windows) that would allow me to work with jpegs and pngs, and have editable text boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) for Windows? Perhaps it is more powerful than you need, but it will certainly allow what you require. At the very least, you can place your text on its own layer, manipulating that from change to change.

Answer (score 3):

It’s been a while since I’ve used it, but [Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/index.html) was very nice and likely easier than GIMP.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Paint.NET, but if it fits the OPs requirements, it's quite likely going to be easier to learn than GIMP.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I haven’t used a Windows PC since I retired a few years ago so this answer might be a bit stale. Paint.Net was really nice though.